# Removing column is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I am trying to remove a column from my database.  I'm running this

```
rails generate RemoveOccupancyFromSpaces occupancy:string
```

But then am getting this error message

```
Could not find generator 'RemoveOccupancyFromSpaces'. Maybe you meant 'resource_route' or 'devise:controllers' or 'active_admin:page'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Did you mean `rails generate migration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is `rails generate migration RemoveOccupancyFromSpaces occupancy:string`

This should yield a file with the correct syntax:

```
class RemoveOccupancyFromSpaces < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :spaces, :occupancy, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `rails generate migration RemoveOccupancyFromSpaces occupancy:string`